# How to create Radial Menu in WPF

Tags: wpf

Can anybody give suggestion how to create Radial menu in WPF,if you give any sample it will be helpfull,

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: After googling "radial menu wpf": http://alexpkent.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/wpf-radial-context-menu-pie-menu/

Comment: I have created radial panel.placed all items ex(Button) in that circle,but i want some thing like animation effect.For example when we press the Button the radial menu open from  the button .when we press again the button the radial menu close.i want animation when menu open and closing..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly suggest you to take a look at what I've done here

[WPF RadialMenu](https://github.com/Julien-Marcou/RadialMenu)

To sum up how it works

First, the radial menu itself :
I created a custom ContentControl **RadialMenu**, which can only have children of the type **RadialMenuItem**,
then in the method `ArrangeOverride` of the radial menu I give to each children its Index Position in the radial menu and the Total Count of children.

Secondly, the items of the radial menu :
Each **RadialMenuItem** is a custom Button with a custom Template, knowing is Index Position inside the Total Count of children, the item is able to create a **PieShape** (with some trigonometry) for its template.

Finally, the central item of the radial menu:
The **RadialMenuCentralItem** is also a custom Button with a custom Template, but the Template is just an Elipse Shape, this item is placed in the radial menu, through the `CentralItem` Property of the radial menu.

Then with some *Trigger*, *Animation*, *Binding* and *DependencyProperty*, you will be able to do that

[image: WPF RadialMenu]